# Probability of getting exactly $x$ dollars in tips

Tags: probability

Anna works as a valet at a popular restaurant. She's so good at her job that everyone leaves a tip.
75% of people whose cars she parks will give her a $\$$2.00 tip. 
15% will give her $\$$3.50 tip. 
And 10% will give her a $\$$6.00 tip

(a) Find her expected average tip for ten customers.

My attempt

$$ E(x) = 0.75(\$2.00) + 0.15(\$3.50) + 0.10(\$6) = \$2.63 $$

(b) Find the probability that the next ten customers will leave her \$20.00 in tips. 
This would be P(X = 20), right? But how to set it up?

(c) Let Y by the number of customers she assists until she receives one tip of each amount, find E(Y)

No clue on this one.

Could someone tell me if I'm on the right track for a, and point me in the right direction for b and c?

Comment: Be careful with dollar signs on this site, as they carry special significance. If you want the dollar sign to be just a dollar sign, you need to have a backslash in front of it: `\$`.

Comment: Thank you, I went back and edited it. It was being weird about that when I entered it in, but I thought I solved it by putting double $$ before and after my formula.

Comment: You figured the expected average for 1 customer. Multiply by 10.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how that would help. That gives me a dollar amount, not a probability. 
I mean, it would suggest that there's a good possibility she'll get close to $20.00, but how do I get a probability from that?

Comment: (c) is the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) but with unequal probabilities. You can do some research if you're interested in it (also in a more general sense, not just this limited scenario).

Comment: Woah, I did look into it...and it looks intensely complex. Far beyond anything we've covered so far. I'm not sure how I'm expected to be able to solve this, if that's the only way.

Comment: @AshleyBewildered, have you gone over Markov chains? It's relatively easy but tedious doing those (the answer is $1792/153$). Like most hard problems, doing specific cases is easy. [Actually, you can might be able to do it with inclusion-exclusion.]

Comment: (Oops, I forgot to add 1 to the above answer.)

Comment: No we haven't yet. I looked through the textbook, and it only mentions them in passing. I'm really at a loss as to how we were expected to solve this. Up until this point, we've only ever dealt with events with the same probability, at least for this kind of problem. I'll read up on them though! Hopefully I can understand how they work.
Can you recommend any sites which might talk about how to apply it in this context? What I'm seeing so far seems much more advanced

Comment: @AshleyBewildered, I found a solution using elementary methods (inclusion-exclusion). (Evidently, I am pretty rusty on my probability...)

Answer (score 1):

(a) You are on the right track. So far you have calculated the expected value for a single tip.

(b) There is only one kind of tip that 10 customers can leave to make \$20. Consider the probability that this event occurs exactly 10 times.

(c) Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is the expected value of $1$ tip. Since expectation is linear, just multiply this value by $10$.
2. Let $x$ be the number of tips which are \$2, $y$ be the number of tips which are \$3.50 and $z$ be the number of tips which are \$6.00. Then we have the following equations:

$$ 200 x + 350 y + 600 z = 2000~\text{(in cents)} $$
$$ x + y + z = 10 $$

In terms of $x$, this will give you the equations:

$$ y = 16 - \frac 85 x$$
$$ z = \frac 35 x - 6 $$

In order for $z$ to be non-negative, $x$ must be $\ge 10$. But since there are only 10 customers, we must have $x\le 10$, hence $x = 10$. You can verify easily that this gives a consistent positive value for $y$ as well. Therefore the only way to get \$20 is to get $10$ \$2 tips.

3. Here's an elementary solution. Consider the event that we DON'T get the necessary tips after $k$ tips. Then we must either have:

   - Not gotten the \$2 tip ($(1-0.75)^k$)
   - Not gotten the \$3.50 tip ($(1-0.15)^k$)
   - Not gotten the \$6.00 tip ($(1-0.10)^k$).

Note that we have overcounted cases in which we do not get two tips (eg, we did not get either \$ 2 tip or \$ 6.00 tip). In order for this to happen, we must get all of the tips to be one kind of tip (all \$2, all \$3.50 or all \$6). This gives the probabilities $0.75^k$, $0.15^k$ and $0.10^k$, which we subtract from the above probabilities. We then take the complement (since we want the event that we DO get the tips):

$$ P(\text{k tips are enough}) = 1 + 0.75^k + 0.15^k + 0.10^k - 0.25^k - 0.85^k - 0.9^k $$

Now to find the probability that exactly $k$ tips are enough, find:

$$ P(\text{k tips are enough}) - P(\text{k - 1 tips are enough})$$

Then use the definition of expectation:
$$\sum_i ip_i$$

and you get the same answer as the Markov Chain below.

---

If you know Markov Chains, this problem is annoying but simple. First verify that the problem is actually a Markov Chain (it is). Then the transition matrix:

$$ P = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{3}{20} & 0 & \frac{3}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{10} & 0 & \frac{3}{20} & 0 & \frac{3}{4} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{20} & \frac{1}{10} & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{4} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{4} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{3}{20} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{17}{20} & 0 & \frac{3}{20} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{9}{10} & \frac{1}{10} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$

and the initial vector $\tau = [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]$ describe your situation.

[image: Markov Chain Directed Graph]

The absorbing state is obviously the 8th row, since we want to find how long it takes to get absorbed, we delete this row and column to get a new matrix $T$. The expected value is given by:

$$ \tau (1+T+T^2 + \cdots) \mathbf 1 = \tau(I-T)^{-1} \mathbf 1$$

where $\mathbf 1$ is a column matrix of all $1s$, to sum over entries of the matrix (the probability of not being absorbed). Then an "easy" calculation gives that the expected value is $\frac{1945}{153}$.

Comment: Thank you so so much! Wow!! This makes so much sense now! You're the best.